# How to display data from a specific week?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to display data from a specific week by giving it a date e.g. `2015-06-01`

This is my table that I want to use to get the week

```
BookingID   CheckInDate CheckOutDate
1           2015-05-25  2015-05-31
2           2015-05-26  2015-06-03
3           2015-06-01  2015-06-07
4           2015-06-01  2015-06-12
```

Here are my database manager code to get the data by week:

```
public static ArrayList GetStatsByWeek(int week, int year)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand();
        ArrayList rmCount = new ArrayList();
        try
        {
            conn.ConnectionString = GSM_CONN_STR;
            conn.Open();
            comm.Connection = conn;
            comm.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(BookingID) as \"TotalCount\" FROM CheckInOut WHERE DATEPART(WEEK,CheckInDate)=@week OR DATEPART(WEEK,CheckOutDate)=@week AND YEAR(CheckInDate)=@year AND Year(CheckOutDate)=@year";
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@week", week);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year", year);
            SqlDataReader dr = comm.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                RoomCounts r = new RoomCounts();
                r.TotalCount = (int)dr["TotalCount"];
                rmCount.Add(r);
            }
            dr.Close();
        }
        catch (SqlException e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
        return rmCount;
    }
```

This is my codes

```
DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(tbxStrtDate.Text);
        double totalPercentage;
        double totalCount = 0;
        int flr2Count = 0;
        int flr3Count = 0;

        CultureInfo cul = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
        int num = cul.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(date, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Sunday);

        //Retrieve all the data
        ArrayList rmC = HotelDB.GetStatsByWeek(num, date.Year);
```

Error Solved and now there is a data problem.
E.g. if I enter `2015-05-27` into `tbxStrtDate` and retrieve,no data is shown even though there is data within that week.

Comment: Could you post the error?

Comment: @wewesthemenace An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in HotelReport.exe

Additional information: Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: add a `(` after your WHERE word

Comment: @cha oh thanks over looked it haha. Updated the codes. But now some data are missing I think. E.g. my tbxStrtDate is 2015-05-27 no data is shown even though there is data within that week. How do I go from there?

Comment: Use this: `DATEPART(WEEK,CheckInDate)<=@week AND DATEPART(WEEK,CheckOutDate)>=@week`

Comment: @cha still the same results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is perfectly fine.

The problem is the difference of "Week number calculation" in your c# method and the SQL server `Datepart` function.

Your function gives week = 21
where as `Datepart` gives week = 22.

So there is no matching result is your query.

Try following to calculate `@week` in your code. It worked with my test data.

```
int num = cul.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(date, CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, DayOfWeek.Sunday);
```

If you are specific about `CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek` in week calculation then you need to find corresponding SQL equivalent.

Comment: I think this is the closes answer that I am looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a checkout date for that

> tbxStrtDate is 2015-05-27

The query is checking checkout date to be of the same year, if the record have no checkout date, you wont be able to match it correctly.

```
AND YEAR(CheckInDate)=@year AND Year(CheckOutDate)=@year";
```

That means that each record to be matched perfectly must have a checkindata and a checkoutdate

Comment: the CheckOutDate is from my database as shown at the top

Comment: Yes you have a checkout date on your sample but do you have a checkout data **FOR 2015-05-27** checkindate

Comment: the 2015-05-27 is not a check in or check out date, it is just a date for me to check on data. or are you meaning I need to have 2 dates of the week,one is the start week and one is the end week? Cos if you look at my codes, it is extracting the week and passing it into the argument as variable num

Comment: This is what you need `DATEPART(WEEK,CheckInDate)<=@week AND DATEPART(WEEK,CheckOutDate)>=@week` you need to capture a range. NOTE: this answer is given first on a comment in your original post

Comment: Testing it with different SQL servers. They yield the same answers (though slight changes in syntax) `SELECT DATEPART(year, '2015-05-27 17:17:26.147') as "year"
 ,DATEPART(week, '2015-05-27 17:17:26.147') as "week"
    ,DATEPART(month, '2015-05-27 17:17:26.147') as "month"
    ,DATEPART(day, '2015-05-27 17:17:26.147') as "day"
    ,DATEPART(dayofyear, '2015-05-27 17:17:26.147') as "dayofyear"
    ,DATEPART(weekday, '2015-05-27 17:17:26.147') as "weekday";` produces `year week month day dayofyear weekday
2015 22 5 27 147 4`

Comment: @GanKAIXIAN Reading that your question is not yet solved, can you post your data with the a checkin and checkout date range that covers 2015-05-27. What week and year are you supplying the **GetStatsByWeek**

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is related to `Logical Operator Precedence`:

> When more than one logical operator is used in a statement, `NOT` is evaluated first, then `AND`, and finally `OR`. Arithmetic, and bitwise, operators are handled before logical operators.

And you have something like this:

```
p OR q AND r AND s
```

That is same as

```
p OR ((q AND r) AND s)
```

And I think you want:

```
(((p OR q) AND r) AND s)
-- or
(p OR q) AND r AND s
```

So, try this:

```
WHERE 
    (DATEPART(WEEK, CheckInDate) = @week 
  OR DATEPART(WEEK, CheckOutDate) = @week) 
 AND YEAR(CheckInDate) = @year 
 AND YEAR(CheckOutDate) = @year
```

> **Note :**
>   When datepart is `week` (`wk`, `ww`) or `weekday` (`dw`), the return value depends on the value that is set by using `SET DATEFIRST`
>
> January 1 of any year defines the starting number for the week datepart, for example: `DATEPART (wk, 'Jan 1, xxxx') = 1`, where xxxx is any year.

So you need to [`SET DATEFIRST`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx).

Comment: Still no difference :)